# Armadillo C++ matrix multiplication with in-place assignment to submatrix

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, armadillo, submatrix, lanczos

Maybe it's a trivial question, but suppose I have two matrices A, B of dimension N x s:

```
arma::mat A(N, s, arma::fill::randu)
arma::mat B(N, s, arma::fill::randu)
```

and I need to write a product of these matrices to a subblock of a larger matrix

```
arma::mat X(M * s, M * s, arma::fill::randu)
```

, which I do in a loop as follows:

```
X.submat(j * s, j * s, (j + 1) * s- 1, (j + 1) * s - 1) = A.t() * B;
```

My question is whether or not Armadillo creates a copy of the product of these matrices and then assigns it to the submatrix, or if the evaluation is performed in-place. The latter would be much more memory and cpu efficient since I am performing this step in a loop over all the blocks (M ~ 1000 steps).

I want to speed up this loop and this is one of the few things I can change. I'd rather not deal with pointers to memory itself and let armadillo deal with that. Can you recommend an efficient way to do it without creating a temporary copy or is this way the best?

The question is related to the Block-Lanczos algorithm for anyone interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official Armadillo site [mentions](https://arma.sourceforge.net/speed.html):

> Armadillo employs a delayed evaluation approach to combine several operations into one and reduce (or eliminate) the need for temporaries. Where applicable, the order of operations is optimised. Delayed evaluation and optimisation are achieved through recursive templates and template meta-programming.

However, [documentation](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) is quite scarce regarding the details of how exactly it is done to the point that even return types of methods aren't specified there, which is, I guess, done with the intention not to scare ordinary users of the library with the level of details (template trickery in particular) typically absent in documentation of similar libraries in higher-level languages from where the users are expected to come from.

Using the source code, though, it isn't very hard to examine what happens, especially with an IntelliSense and Debugger. What helps is that Armadillo is templated and thus is implemented in headers, so we can see from IDE what happens up to the point where underlying (compiled, with platform-specific implementation) BLAS routines are called.

So, your `A.t() * B` represents the computation which has to be done in a context where the result is finally needed. It is of type `arma::Glue<arma::Op<arma::dmat, arma::op_htrans>, arma::dmat, arma::glue_times>` and contains references to two `arma::Base`-derived operands, which in our case are an `arma::Op<arma::dmat, arma::op_htrans>` representing `A.t()` (which itself contains reference to `A`, of course) and an `arma::dmat` representing `B`. The third `arma::Glue`'s template argument specifies operation itself, which is `arma::glue_times` for multiplication. `arma::glue_times::apply` eventually gets called to perform the multiplication, and, through several layers of indirection with various `if`'s, except some special (e.g. small-matrices) cases, BLAS `[x]gemm` (`dgemm` for `double` matrices in our case) function gets called [like this](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/12.6.x/include/armadillo_bits/mul_gemm.hpp?ref_type=heads#L322) (from `arma::gemm<...>::apply_blas_type`):

```
// ...
      #elif defined(ARMA_USE_BLAS)
        {
        arma_extra_debug_print("blas::gemm()");
        
        arma_debug_assert_blas_size(A,B);
        
        const char trans_A = (do_trans_A) ? ( is_cx<eT>::yes ? 'C' : 'T' ) : 'N';
        const char trans_B = (do_trans_B) ? ( is_cx<eT>::yes ? 'C' : 'T' ) : 'N';
        
        const blas_int m   = blas_int(C.n_rows);
        const blas_int n   = blas_int(C.n_cols);
        const blas_int k   = (do_trans_A) ? blas_int(A.n_rows) : blas_int(A.n_cols);
        
        const eT local_alpha = (use_alpha) ? alpha : eT(1);
        
        const blas_int lda = (do_trans_A) ? k : m;
        const blas_int ldb = (do_trans_B) ? n : k;
        
        const eT local_beta  = (use_beta) ? beta : eT(0);
        
        arma_extra_debug_print( arma_str::format("blas::gemm(): trans_A = %c") % trans_A );
        arma_extra_debug_print( arma_str::format("blas::gemm(): trans_B = %c") % trans_B );
        
        blas::gemm<eT>
          (
          &trans_A,
          &trans_B,
          &m,
          &n,
          &k,
          &local_alpha,
          A.mem,
          &lda,
          B.mem,
          &ldb,
          &local_beta,
          C.memptr(),
          &m
          );
        }
// ...
```

(where `blas::gemm` is a very [thin wrapper](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/12.6.x/include/armadillo_bits/translate_blas.hpp?ref_type=heads#L57) dealing with choosing appropriate `[x]gemm` depending on number type and with Fortran hidden string length arguments if needed)

As you can see, the information about whether the argument matrices have to be interpreted as transposed for the purposes of multiplication is passed to `gemm` in a [standard way](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1.html#gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1) through one-character string arguments, so there is no need to create a temporary matrix for `A.t()`. And `arma::glue_times::apply` does not, instead it "unwraps" `arma::Op<arma::dmat, arma::op_htrans>` to setting `do_trans_A` as `true` (and `do_trans_B` is false since second argument is just `arma::dmat`) template arguments (see [here](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/12.6.x/include/armadillo_bits/glue_times_meat.hpp?ref_type=heads#L28)) which are used above to construct `trans_A` and `trans_B` characters.

Another aspect of how `blas::gemm` is called above is that it uses (together with dimensions of matrices, of course) a single pointer `C.memptr()` as an output argument (where `C` is `Mat<eT>&` output argument of `apply_blas_type`), so, in particular, the storage to which `blas::gemm` writes to is assumed to be a contiguous one (otherwise, it wouldn't know how to access rows past the first). When you assign to some matrix `D` like `D = A.t() * B` this isn't the problem since `D` has contiguous storage and `operator=` for `Glue<T1, T2, glue_type>` argument is [implemented](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/12.6.x/include/armadillo_bits/Mat_meat.hpp?ref_type=heads#L5590) to just call `glue_type::apply`.

However, `arma::subview` can't be guaranteed to refer to contiguous storage, so when we assign to it we wouldn't be able to call BLAS functions with something like its "memptr" as output as it's done above for `arma::Mat` argument. Thus, Armadillo creates a temporary output matrix and then copies from it to a subview. In particular, `arma::subview<eT>::operator=` ([source](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/12.6.x/include/armadillo_bits/subview_meat.hpp?ref_type=heads#L533)) calls [helper](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/12.6.x/include/armadillo_bits/subview_meat.hpp?ref_type=heads#L141) `inplace_op<op_internal_equ>` where the temporary matrix is created (`B` below) and is copied into subview (`s`) col-by-col (not "row-by-row" because matrices are stored in [column-major order](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat)):

```
// ...
      if((s.aux_row1 == 0) && (s_n_rows == s.m.n_rows))
        {
        if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_equ  >::yes)  { arrayops::copy         ( s.colptr(0), B.memptr(), s.n_elem ); }
        if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_plus >::yes)  { arrayops::inplace_plus ( s.colptr(0), B.memptr(), s.n_elem ); }
        if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_minus>::yes)  { arrayops::inplace_minus( s.colptr(0), B.memptr(), s.n_elem ); }
        if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_schur>::yes)  { arrayops::inplace_mul  ( s.colptr(0), B.memptr(), s.n_elem ); }
        if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_div  >::yes)  { arrayops::inplace_div  ( s.colptr(0), B.memptr(), s.n_elem ); }
        }
      else
        {
        for(uword ucol=0; ucol < s_n_cols; ++ucol)
          {
          if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_equ  >::yes)  { arrayops::copy         ( s.colptr(ucol), B.colptr(ucol), s_n_rows ); }
          if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_plus >::yes)  { arrayops::inplace_plus ( s.colptr(ucol), B.colptr(ucol), s_n_rows ); }
          if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_minus>::yes)  { arrayops::inplace_minus( s.colptr(ucol), B.colptr(ucol), s_n_rows ); }
          if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_schur>::yes)  { arrayops::inplace_mul  ( s.colptr(ucol), B.colptr(ucol), s_n_rows ); }
          if(is_same_type<op_type, op_internal_div  >::yes)  { arrayops::inplace_div  ( s.colptr(ucol), B.colptr(ucol), s_n_rows ); }
          }
        }
// ...
```

(Note that in the case when `s_n_rows == s.m.n_rows`, i.e. subview is actually contiguous, a single `arrayops::copy` (which itself is just a `memcpy` wrapper) is called instead of for each column in a loop, but the temporary matrix is still created. Also, `op_internal_schur` is for element-wise multiplication)

So, summing up, no intermediate matrix will be created when evaluating `A.t() * B`, but before actual assignment to a subview one matrix will be created. And if you want to use BLAS optimized functions, you can't get around it. But you can try implementing multiplication directly into your discontinuous subview manually using `arma::Mat::at` indexing (which isn't bounds-checked) and measure if you want, though I doubt that avoiding one temporary matrix creation will outweigh the loss of BLAS optimizations (and, among other things, contiguousness of the output buffer during computations there may make them more cache-friendly).

Comment: Wow, thank very much for the very elaborate answer!! I knew that armadillo uses lazy evaluation to calculate products of multiple matrices, but I was unsure whether the assignment is performed similarly. I suppose the loss in performance is not big enough to play around with optimizing it myself. Thanks again!